# How github uses SSH to exchange data?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I only understood one half of the process of SSH Authentication:

1. I give my **public key A** to Github
2. Github encrypts the data then send it to me
3. I am the only to read it because I have the private key of A , Good

Now when I'm pushing, I don't have the **public key B** of Github to do same on the opposite direction .. or is it stored somewhere ? Also if it works like that, if someone want to push stuff he just have to steal the public key B "given/stored in .git" of  Github linked to my account and push stuff that I don't want

I know i'm missing something, so I hope someone could explain it with further details

Comment: ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc4251.txt

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/press/internet-protocol-journal/back-issues/table-contents-46/124-ssh.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when I'm pushing, I don't have the public key B of Github to do same on the opposite direction .. or is it stored somewhere ?

Github.com sends it's public key when establishing SSH connection. If you are using OpenSSH on some kind of UNIX, it is stored in file `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`. In fact, it gets there the first time you connect to Github via SSH, when you answer "yes" to the following prompt:

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

By answering "yes" you tell your SSH client that you trust the owner of the key which has public part with the specified hash `nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8`. This ensures that you are connected to the true github.com and not to some fraud host which pretends to be github.com. (Note that the given fingerprint matches the one on the official github [SSH help page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection).) Next time you connect to the host and receive the public key from it, OpenSSH will iterate through entries in `known_hosts` file, find the corresponding fingerprint and will assume that the host is authentic and will not prompt you anymore.

But this is all about authentication of Github to you, i. e. **whether you trust the server or not**.

Now to the second part, which involves the proof of **your authenticity to the server**:

> Also if it works like that, if someone want to push stuff he just have to steal the public key B "given/stored in .git" of Github linked to my account and push stuff that I don't want

Not like that. Github allows to do any kind of stuff only to owners of private keys, public counterparts for which are registered on your account preferences page. Stealing public key is pointless since it's *public*, i.e. it's not secret.

Let's imagine someone knows the public key for your Github account and tries to push some change to your repo. He connects to Github and sends your public key to it so that Github believed it is talking to the real account owner. But to make sure of that Github challenges the client with a decryption task which only the owner of the private key can accomplish. Since only you have the private key for your account, only you can push to your repos on your behalf. This is why you should keep your private keys carefully.

Answer (score 0):

SSH server (GitHub) knows that the only one who can access the repo is the one who has the private key. And only those who have the private key can decrypt its messages.

So the server uses it. It generates a random number, encrypts it with the public key and asks the client to read it. If he reads it correctly, he must have the private key.